# Libreoffice calc: pagebreak within row?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice

When printing a LibreOffice Table,
LibreOffice will automaticaly place the pagebreaks so that they appear after/before a row.
When having many tall rows this results in a heavy paper-usage. How can I allow LibreOffice to break within a row?

Answer (score 0):

The LibreOffice suite provides printing areas for manual adjusting output document.

1. To switch to this mode click `View -> Page break Preview`
2. Now select first area which you would like to print and click  `Format -> Print Ranges -> Define`
3. Select other zones consequently and press `Format -> Print Ranges -> Add` on each

[image]

You may manually edit these zones in this dialog `Format -> Print Ranges -> Edit`

You may also adjust default settings in sheet style menu. Select tab **Styles** on sidebar. Select subtab **Page Styles**. Select **Default**, right click Modify and select last tab called **Sheet**. Section Scale and PAge order is what you want.

You may find additional help on [LibreOffice help page](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Welcome_to_the_Calc_Help)